# Quartz repeat execution 5 times every day

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz to schedule my jobs,
I need to execute a job at 2:00am every day and repeat the execution 5 times every 10 minutes, any ideas?
the result should be: 2:00     2:10     2:20     2:30     2:40

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to repeat *once* every 10 minutes, I suspect ? And what's the specific question ?

Answer (score 4):

I would look at the Quartz [CronTrigger](http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/CronTriggers%20Tutorial.html), and particularly the usage of / to specify *every 'n' minutes/hours* whatever.

I think you would need

```
0 0,10,20,30,40 2 * * ?
```

to fire at 2am and then 2.10am-2.40am every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Just specify the schedule times as a cron string for the CronTrigger like this:

```
0 0,10,20,30,40 2 * * *
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CronTrigger with a cron expression that describes the exact times you want it run. For every day at 2:00, 2:10, 2:20, 2:30, 2:40, use:

```
0 0,10,20,30,40 2 * * ?
```

Comment: thanks, im new in quartz and I never used Cron Trigger, I will try it

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution would be to simply have 5 tasks, one for every 10 minutes.